# Select All combinations of rows for a*b=total <=X

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a situation about writing a query to find and insert into table B all combinations of rows from table A, where the condition is:

a x b=total from row1
c x d=total from row2 ...etc where count(total)<=X
"a" price of item
"b" quantity of item

Idea is to have all combinations like example

For 100$ dollars i can buy:

```
2 tshirt, 1 jacket, 1 pants
```

or

```
1 tshirt, 2 jacket, 1 pants
```

...etc

Creating a cursor will help me run the query for each row, but how to split the number in col.quantity in the same time ?

Comment: Do you a sample data?

Comment: You're much more likely to get help if you post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with DDL, sample data, your existing code and a _specific_ question.

Comment: Have you ever heard of the "knapsack" problem? This is known to be NP hard, so you will most likely not be able to solve that using a simple query.

Comment: hello  Wolfgang Kais, this is exactly what I am looking for. i see there are a lot of examples on sites to implement it on SQL SERVER./

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will first write what I understood,

- we would have a table of items, each item would have a price,
- we have an amount of money and we want to buy as many as possible
  items
- we want the items to have the same weight as the two examples
  provided "2 tshirt, 1 jacket, 1 pants or 1 tshirt, 2 jacket, 1 pants"
  did not specify a solution with one item but tried to use all the
  items.

So how to determine the Qty for each item to utilize most of the money that we have.

I think this can be described in a different way to be more clear, like for example:- one person goes in a shop and would like to buy each of the items available but if he has some more money left he want to know what other items he can buy with it. if the items are not a lot and the money is not a lot, this can be easy, but if the items are a lot and the money a lot too, I can see that this may be a problem. so lets find a solution.

```
Declare @Items Table (
    Item varchar(250),Price decimal
)

insert into @Items values 
 ('tshirt',30)
,('jacket',30)
,('pants' ,10)
--,('shoe' ,15)   ---extra items for testing
--,('socks',5)    ---extra items for testing

Declare @total int=100 -- your X
Declare @ItemsCount int
Declare @flag int
Declare @ItemsSum decimal
Declare @AllItmsQty int
select @ItemsCount=count(*),@ItemsSum=sum(price),@flag=POWER(2,count(*)) From @Items

select @AllItmsQty=@total/cast(@ItemsSum as int)

;with Numbers(n) as (
    --generat numbers from 1,2,3,... @flag
    select 1 union all 
    select (n+1) n from Numbers where n<@flag
),ItemsWithQty as (
    select *,Price*n [LineTotal] from @Items,Numbers
),Combination as (
    select items.*,Numbers.n-1 [CombinationId] from @Items items,Numbers
),CombinationWithSeq as (
    select *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by [CombinationId] order by [CombinationId]) [seq] 
        from Combination
),CombinationWithSeqQty as (
    select *,case when (CombinationId & power(2,seq-1))>0 then 1 else 0 end +@AllItmsQty  [qty] 
    from CombinationWithSeq
),CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal as (
    select *,Price*qty [SubTotal] from CombinationWithSeqQty
)
select 
    --CombinationId,
    sum(subtotal) [Total],
    replace(
        replace(
            STRING_AGG( 
            case when (Qty=0) then 'NA' else (cast(Qty as varchar(5))+' '+Item)
                end
            ,'+')
            ,'+NA','')
            ,'NA+','')  [Items] 
    from CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal   
    group by CombinationId
    having sum(subtotal)<=@total
```

The result would be as follow:-

```
Total   Items
=====   ===========================
100     2 tshirt+1 jacket+1 pants
100     1 tshirt+2 jacket+1 pants
80      1 tshirt+1 jacket+2 pants
70      1 tshirt+1 jacket+1 pants
```

if I add the other two items we would get

```
Total   Items
=====   ===========================
100     1 tshirt+1 jacket+2 pants+1 shoe+1 socks
95      1 tshirt+1 jacket+1 pants+1 shoe+2 socks
90      1 tshirt+1 jacket+1 pants+1 shoe+1 socks
```

ok so the query is giving the final result not the table B, that you described to have a x b or item price multiplied by qty and sub total , well we can display that one very easily by filtering witch combination we selected, if we are selecting the first one that would be the nearest to the amount we can change the last part of the query to show table B you need.

```
),CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal as (
    select *,Price*qty [SubTotal] from CombinationWithSeqQty
),Results as (
select 
    CombinationId,
    sum(subtotal) [Total],
    replace(
        replace(
            STRING_AGG( 
            case when (Qty=0) then 'NA' else (cast(Qty as varchar(5))+' '+Item)
                end
            ,'+')
            ,'+NA','')
            ,'NA+','')  [Items] 
    from CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal   
    group by CombinationId
    having sum(subtotal)<=@total
    --order by [Total] desc
)
select item, price, qty, SubTotal from CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal t where t.CombinationId in
(select top(1) CombinationId from Results order by [Total] desc)
```

The result would be as below:-

```
item    price   qty SubTotal
=====   =====   === =======
tshirt  30      1   30
jacket  30      1   30
pants   10      2   20
shoe    15      1   15
socks   5       1   5
```

or if we run it with only the items you provided the result would be as below:-

```
item    price   qty SubTotal
======  ===     === =======
tshirt  30      2   60
jacket  30      1   30
pants   10      1   10
```

if we dont want to use 'STRING_AGG' or we dont have it, we can manage its same function by adding some CTE's that will do the same job, as the 'STRING_AGG' was only combining the results in a (qty + item + comma), so the below solution may help.

```
Declare @Items Table (Item varchar(250),Price decimal)

insert into @Items values 
 ('tshirt',30)
,('jacket',30)
,('pants' ,10)
--,('shoes' ,15)   ---extra items for testing
--,('socks',5)    ---extra items for testing

Declare @total int=100 -- your X
Declare @ItemsCount int
Declare @flag int
Declare @ItemsSum decimal
Declare @AllItmsQty int
select @ItemsCount=count(*),@ItemsSum=sum(price),@flag=POWER(2,count(*)) From @Items

select @AllItmsQty=@total/cast(@ItemsSum as int)

;with Numbers(n) as (
    --generat numbers from 1,2,3,... @flag
    select 1 union all 
    select (n+1) n from Numbers where n<@flag
),ItemsWithQty as (
    select *,Price*n [LineTotal] from @Items,Numbers
),Combination as (
    select items.*,Numbers.n-1 [CombinationId] from @Items items,Numbers
),CombinationWithSeq as (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by [CombinationId] order by [CombinationId]) [seq] from Combination
),CombinationWithSeqQty as (
    select *,case when (CombinationId & power(2,seq-1))>0 then 1 else 0 end +@AllItmsQty  [qty] from CombinationWithSeq
),CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal as (
    select *,Price*qty [SubTotal] from CombinationWithSeqQty
),CombinationWithTotal as (
--to find only the combinations that are less or equal to the Total
    select 
        CombinationId,
        sum(subtotal) [Total]
        from CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal   
        group by CombinationId
        having sum(subtotal)<=@total
),DetailAnswer as (
    select s.*,t.Total,cast(s.qty as varchar(20))+' ' +s.Item QtyItem from CombinationWithTotal t
    inner join CombinationWithSeqQtySubTotal s on s.CombinationId=t.CombinationId
),DetailAnswerFirst as (
    select *,cast(QtyItem as varchar(max)) ItemList from DetailAnswer t where t.seq=1
    union all
    select t.*,cast((t.QtyItem+'+'+x.ItemList) as varchar(max)) ItemList from DetailAnswer t
        inner join DetailAnswerFirst x on x.CombinationId=t.CombinationId and x.seq+1=t.seq
)
select CombinationId,Total,ItemList from DetailAnswerFirst where seq=@ItemsCount order by Total desc
--select * from DetailAnswer --remark the above line and unremark this one for the details that you want to go in Table B
```

if any of the assumptions are wrong or if you need some description I would be happy to help.

Comment: code looks like working, but cant use the whole code because i am using sql server 2008, and it does not recognize  STRING_AGG . sorry i forgot to mention it

Comment: i am looking for a solution like "knapsack" problem like Wolfgang Kais  said

Comment: I edit my answer to include a solution without STRING_AGG, hope it will hlep.

Comment: It can do the job. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way to get the possible combinations is via self-joins and joins to numbers.

If you want combinations of 3, then use 3 self-joins.
And 3 joins to a number table or CTE for each joined "Items" table.

The way the `ON` criteria are used, is to minimize the impact of all that joining.

You could also take the SQL from the COMBOS CTE, and use it to first insert it into a temporary table.

**For example:**

```
declare @PriceLimit decimal(10,2) = 100;

WITH COMBOS AS
(
    SELECT 
     i1.id as id1, i2.id as id2, i3.id as id3, 
     n1.n as n1, n2.n as n2, n3.n as n3,
     (n1.n + n2.n + n3.n) AS TotalItems,
     (i1.Price * n1.n + i2.Price * n2.n + i3.Price * n3.n) as TotalCost
    FROM Items i1
    JOIN Items i2 ON i2.id > i1.id AND i2.Price < @PriceLimit
    JOIN Items i3 ON i3.id > i2.id AND i3.Price < @PriceLimit
    JOIN Nums n1 
      ON n1.n between 1 and FLOOR(@PriceLimit/i1.Price)
     AND (i1.Price * n1.n) < @PriceLimit
    JOIN Nums n2 
      ON n2.n between 1 and FLOOR(@PriceLimit/i2.Price)
     AND (i1.Price * n1.n + i2.Price * n2.n) < @PriceLimit
    JOIN Nums n3 
      ON n3.n between 1 and FLOOR(@PriceLimit/i3.Price) 
     AND (i1.Price * n1.n + i2.Price * n2.n + i3.Price * n3.n) <= @PriceLimit
     AND (i1.Price * n1.n + i2.Price * n2.n + i3.Price * (n3.n+1)) > @PriceLimit
    WHERE i1.Price < @PriceLimit
)
SELECT 
 c.TotalItems, c.TotalCost,
 CONCAT (c.n1,' ',item1.Name,', ',c.n2,' ',item2.Name,', ',c.n3,' ',item3.Name) AS ItemList
FROM COMBOS c
LEFT JOIN Items item1 ON item1.id = c.id1
LEFT JOIN Items item2 ON item2.id = c.id2
LEFT JOIN Items item3 ON item3.id = c.id3
ORDER BY c.TotalCost desc, c.TotalItems desc, c.id1, c.id2, c.id3;
```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9b5c83f96f0b5d6d2264e95fd2b5e8bc)*

**Test result:**

```
 TotalItems | TotalCost | ItemList                   
 ---------- | --------- | ---------------------------
          7 | 100.00    | 1 pants, 1 tshirt, 5 socks 
          6 | 100.00    | 1 jacket, 1 tshirt, 4 socks
          6 | 100.00    | 1 pants, 2 tshirt, 3 socks 
          5 | 100.00    | 1 jacket, 1 pants, 3 socks 
          5 | 100.00    | 1 jacket, 2 tshirt, 2 socks
          5 | 100.00    | 1 pants, 3 tshirt, 1 socks 
          5 | 100.00    | 2 pants, 1 tshirt, 2 socks 
          3 | 90.00     | 1 jacket, 1 pants, 1 tshirt
```

Comment: Thanks. Well, this works to find all combinations of 3. So it's not really intended to solve a knapsack problem. But for that you would need to set rules about what counts as optimal.

Comment: I am working on writing an algorithm to solve the knapsack problem in sql server and almost finished it... but while testing, it looks not to good as i am using while loop 4-5 times within the query and it takes some time to be executed.
for example, if i have 30 items with most of them price lower than parameter, there are shown more than 2000 combinations and it takes about 2min to finish